# How to initailize a field to be used in other test spec file in protractor

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I have written below function in one of the page object file in Protractor.

```
  case 'History':
                          console.log('To do for History');
                          this.artifactsHistory.getText().then((text)=>{
                           console.log(text)
                           this.historyMessage = text
                           console.log('this.historyMessage is '+this.historyMessage)
                          })
```

Here i want to get the text in one of the field/variable and use the same in the spec file. I am trying to use 'this.historyMessage = text', but on using the same in the spec file, nothing is printed.
Could you please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, logging, element,by } from 'protractor';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;
  let title;
  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display welcome message', async() => {
    page.navigateTo();
    title =  await page.getTitleText();
    console.log(title)
    expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('scriptless app is running!');
  });

  it('print the global title variable',()=>{
    console.log(title) 
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
    const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
    expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
    } as logging.Entry));
  });
});
```

Declare a variable of global scope. Assign value to it in one it() and then use it in other.

And your `console.log(text)` prints something?